# Application insights logs get lost

Tags: c#, nlog, azure-application-insights

I have a couple of `.NET` services hosted on Azure, and all of them are connected to Application Insights via NLog adapter (`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget` nuget package). The usage is pretty simple:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType().Name);
logger.LogInfo("Received request from user " + userId);
var result = DoSomething(userId);
if(result.Success)
    logger.LogInfo("Request successful for " + userId);
else
    logger.LogError("Request failed for " + userId);
```

The Application Insights target is configured in app/web.config in a standard way:

```
<nlog>
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" name="aiTarget" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="aiTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Everything seems to be working, but I recently started to notice that some logs are missing in Azure. For example, for a given `userId`, Azure contains `Received request` message, but no `successful` or `failed` messages (and I know for sure no exceptions happened during the flow). Also, for some `userId`s logs are missing completely. I tried Application Insights `Search` and `Analytics` tab, but both seem to be missing some portion of the log entries that my applications send.

This happens across multiple services, with no apparent reason, and no errors/exceptions to be seen anywhere on Azure. Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Comment: Application running in Azure? or Azure Function? Do you execute `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` before application-exit?

Comment: For .NET SDK there is adaptive sampling turned on by default. Did you turn it off?

Comment: @RolfKristensen, most of these applications are App Services and WebJobs, so they don't really have an "application exit". They are supposed to be long running and write a lot of logs in the process.

Comment: @ZakiMa, how do you turn off sampling when using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget` ?

Comment: This is the default configuration (in ApplicationInsights.config): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#frequently-asked-questions. Right now one section (which excludes Event telemetry type) covers Trace telemetry type. One approach is to do <ExcludedTypes>Event, Trace</ExcludedTypes>

Comment: @AndreBorges, did you get the solution? can you please share your findings?